# How to set shipping cost when using PayPal's Rest API?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In PayPal MPL library, one can set the tax and shipping cost from the code. Is there any proper document or any sample application that guide us to set tax or shipping cost when using Rest API. I have try to set shipping cost from sand box account, but unable to log-in with id (that was auto-generated when creating PayPal Developer Account).

Answer (score 0):

I found the official PayPal Android Developer's Guide for you.

[PayPal Android Developer's guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf)

Page 23 of the developers guide has a reference to Shipping and Tax:

setTax(String tax)
setShipping(String shipping)

This developer's guide should help you add tax and shipping to your mobile application.